# How to fill each column with responsive background? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like each column to have its own background. I would like it to be fixed height as the columns are but so the width can adapt.

This is my html for the 3 blocks.

```
<section class="no-pad clearfix">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 no-pad">
                <div class="feature-box bg-hfc">
                    <h1 class="text-white">Hellfire Citadel</h1>
                    <p class="text-white">Hellfire Assault<br>Iron Reaver<br>Kormrok<br>Kilrogg Deadeye<br>Hellfire High Council<br>Gorefiend<br>Shadow-Lord Iskar<br>Socrethar the Eternal<br>Tyrant Velhari<br>Fel Lord Zakuun<br>Xhul'horac<br>Mannoroth<br>Archimonde<br></p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 no-pad">
                <div class="feature-box bg-brf">
                    <h1 class="text-white">Blackrock Foundry</h1>
                    <p class="text-white">Oregorger<br>Gruul<br>The Blast Furnace<br>Hans'gar and Franzok<br>Flamebender Ka\'graz<br>Kromog<br>Beastlord Darmac<br>Operator Thogar<br>The Iron Maidens<br>Blackhand<br><br><br><br> 
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 no-pad">
                <div class="feature-box bg-hm">
                    <h1 class="text-white">Highmaul</h1>
                    <p class="text-white">Kargath Bladefist<br>The Butcher<br>Brackenspore<br>Tectus<br>Twin Ogron<br>Ko'ragh<br>Imperator Mar'gok<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>

                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

This is my css, each column is to have its own background:

```
.bg-hfc{
    background-image:url('../img/hfcbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}

.bg-brf{
    background-image:url('../img/brfbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}

.bg-hm{
    background-image:url('../img/hmbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position: center !important;
}
```

you can find my currently not working demo here: http://endless-guild.com/wow_progress/show-progress.php

This is what I would like it to look like: http://cl.ly/image/1z3I33281R1b
Ignore the guide lines :)

I did lot of digging around but cant figure out what im doing wrong here. I know the code is awful. I am not very good at this and I would appreciate your help. Many love!

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @code How to fill each column with responsive background? As you can see in my demo its not working for some reason. This is what I would like it to look like http://cl.ly/image/1z3I33281R1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.
Turn out 16 hours of coding is bit too much and I was being absolute moron and not even going to say how badly i messed up haha.

Anyway! The css I was after was this:

```
background-image: url('../img/brfbg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

You can see final result here:

[Demo](http://endless-guild.com/wow_progress/show-progress.php)

Answer (score 0):

you almost had it right: Try this **NEW** and fixed HTML:

```
<section class="no-pad clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 no-pad">
        <div class="feature-box bg-hfc col-xs-12">
            <h1 class="text-white">Hellfire Citadel</h1>

            <p class="text-white">Hellfire Assault
                <br>Iron Reaver
                <br>Kormrok
                <br>Kilrogg Deadeye
                <br>Hellfire High Council
                <br>Gorefiend
                <br>Shadow-Lord Iskar
                <br>Socrethar the Eternal
                <br>Tyrant Velhari
                <br>Fel Lord Zakuun
                <br>Xhul'horac
                <br>Mannoroth
                <br>Archimonde
                <br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 no-pad">
        <div class="feature-box bg-brf col-xs-12">
             <h1 class="text-white">Blackrock Foundry</h1>

            <p class="text-white">Oregorger
                <br>Gruul
                <br>The Blast Furnace
                <br>Hans'gar and Franzok
                <br>Flamebender Ka\'graz
                <br>Kromog
                <br>Beastlord Darmac
                <br>Operator Thogar
                <br>The Iron Maidens
                <br>Blackhand
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 no-pad">
        <div class="feature-box bg-hm col-xs-12">
             <h1 class="text-white">Highmaul</h1>

            <p class="text-white">Kargath Bladefist
                <br>The Butcher
                <br>Brackenspore
                <br>Tectus
                <br>Twin Ogron
                <br>Ko'ragh
                <br>Imperator Mar'gok
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You where just missing the `col-xs-12` on the classes.

---

**EDIT**

Try this CSS as well :)

```
.bg-hfc{
    background-image:url('../img/hfcbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg-brf{
    background-image:url('../img/brfbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg-hm{
    background-image:url('../img/hmbg.png') !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @user1783920, try that updated CSS as well please :)

Comment: @user1783920, hmm, very odd indeed! Are you sure your image locations are correct?

Comment: @user1783920, I have an idea. For your image url try removing one of the dots, and then see if it works :)

Comment: Image URLs are fine, using brackets and it finds the path fine :/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
.bg-hfc{
    background-image: url('../img/hfcbg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9nc21kgo/).

Comment: Hi, thanks but still doesnt work.. I dont get it :(
If I do something like 
'.bg-hfc{
background-color: #136480 !important;
}'
It works.. yet I cant set it to be image

Comment: what do you mean? see the fiddle ^

Comment: Yeah, i really dont get it :( for some reason whatever I do I cant give it background image.. But just solid colour works. The image math is fine as well triple checked

Comment: try absolute path to your image